# Log insertion to log-table after deleting the file in Azure Blob Storaage - Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, azure, logging, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I try to monitor my blob storage. I want to inserd log to the log table after each change to the blob storage (e.g. updating files, deleting, creating, moving files etc.). I want to get information about the user, date, etc. who made the change. I read a lot of topics but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor your blob actions using Log Analytics Workspace.

You just need to enable your Storage Account Diagnostic settings and thereby you can monitor blob actions in Log Analytics workspace. You can also use KQL and retrieve the selected data.

For enabling Navigate as below
Storage Account > Diagnostic settings (preview) [under Monitoring] > Enable the once that you want to monitor.
[image]

and Now go to your Log Analytics Workspace > Logs[image]

when you run it you can find the logs that were performed in blob of Storage Account
[image]

For more information you can refer [HERE](https://visualbi.com/blogs/microsoft/powerbi/utilizing-azure-log-analytics-workspace-azure-storage-account-logs/).